# Prior Art Request for US 20140038722 A1 "Universal virtual entity transformation"

Tags: prior-art-request, pre-grant, us20140038722

https://www.google.com/patents/US20140038722

> 1. A method of transforming a virtual entity from a first game to be useable in a second game comprising the steps of:
>
>    a. Obtaining a set
>      of created correlations between characteristics defining the virtual
>      entity in the first game with characteristics available in the second
>      game to define a virtual entity;
>
>    b. applying the correlations to the
>      characteristics defining the virtual entity in the first game to
>      create a set correlated characteristics;
>
>    c. creating a new virtual
>      entity in the second game with the correlated characteristics
>
>    d. the
>      created correlations and applying the correlations to create the new
>      virtual entity being independent of a player selection or input, and
>
>    e. storing the created correlations in a non-transitory memory.

This appears to apply to video games in a series that allow you to import saves from previous games. Mass Effect 2 (2010) is a recent example. Quest for Glory 2 (1990) was one of the first games to allow this. Are these valid examples of prior art for this patent? Are there any earlier examples?

Answer (score 2):

Ultima 5 ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_V:_Warriors_of_Destiny](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultima_V%3a_Warriors_of_Destiny)) allowed the import of characters from Ultima 4.  This was mentioned in a review http://spoonyexperiment.com/game-reviews/ultima-5-warriors-of-destiny/ around the 7:14 mark.  The game was made in 1988.

Comment: Going back further, Bards Tale 2 (1986) imported characters from Ultima (3?) and Wizardry of the same era.  Given that they were all D&D knock-offs, the translation was minimal, but it's still there.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that Pokemon is another example of prior art, yes?  It's possible to take a pokemon from [Pokemon FireRed all the way through to Pokemon X](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon/trade-from-firered-to-x/).

I remember Baldur's Gate II allowed you to import your character from Baldur's Gate I, too.  It even works on the modernized [Enhanced Editions](http://steamcommunity.com/app/257350/discussions/0/666826250797787467/).

Answer (score 0):

What about all the character converters that have already been published?

[Pathfinder](http://paizo.com/products/btpy89m6?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Conversion-Guide)

[Shadowrun](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/116922/Shadowrun-Fifth-Edition-Character-Conversion-Guide)

[Some homebrew converter](http://www.easydamus.com/BasicD20toChaosium.pdf)